# How to install latest stable version of node.js on centos 7

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, centos, nvm

How to install latest stable version of node.js on centos 7 ?

What is the easiest way to install latest node.js + nvm + npm on CentOS 7

Without downloading the source code and compiling it.

Answer (score 1):

Node builds binaries as well as providing source.  For example you could grab `https://nodejs.org/download/release/v5.3.0/node-v5.3.0-linux-x64.tar.gz` and then extract into the proper hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

woo, I just instlled successfully these days, the offical stable version I just forgot.Beause in China sometimes I cannot open its offical net (you know that)
you can use following command to install:

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.6.9.tar.gz 

tar xvf node-v0.6.9.tar.gz 

cd node-v0.6.9

yum install gcc gcc-c++ openssl-devel #一些软件包/nodejs need this package 

./configure

make && make install

node--version #查看版本信息/check version info
```

if you wanna install other version just open [http://nodejs.org/dist](http://nodejs.org/dist/)
to check

Finish